# Envio de ArrayList e valor Geral para outra Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, arraylist

Estou criando uma Activity, por exemplo A e nela tenho que adicionar dados de Lançamentos (Esta classe eu Serializei), como nome, tipo, etc... e vou adicionando também o valor geral atualizado na tela e tenho o botão de listar, onde vou listar todos lançamentos e ai que mora meu unico problema...

Como enviar o `array` para esta `activity`? E quando eu voltar para tela principal vou precisar da lista novamente e o valor geral...

Comment: Aconselho você fazer um [Tuor](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) aqui para aprender melhor com fazer boas perguntas e obter respostas melhores ainda.

Comment: Ficou bem confuso mesmo. Seria bom vc nos dar exemplo do código, de onde você pega essa lista, e etc

Comment: Oii, pessoal... Desculpa... é minha primeira vez aqui, mas pode deixar que estarei melhorando... obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer isto:

```
  Intent it = new Intent(this, proximaAcvitivity.class);
  it.putExtra("dadosC", vetorConta);  
  startAcvitity(it);
```

O exemplo foi visto neste link: http://respostas.guj.com.br/29500-como-enviar-uma-arraylist-para-outra-activity-e-depois-receber-ela-atualizada

Para na volta não recarregar lista, terá que não chamar o metodo que recarrega. Sua tela continuara igual antes de ter trocado de activity.

Comment: Oii! Obrigado pela ajuda... mas o que eu precisava era trabalhar mesmo com startActivityForResult... consegui enviar meu Array para outra Activity e voltar.

Comment: Agora to pesquisando uma forma de clicar na minha lista View e ao clicar os dados do item voltará na activity de edição, onde posso editar o item ou excluir... Tem um exemplo para me indicar?

Comment: não da pra fazer o mesmo caminho de volta?

Comment: Credito que você precise trocar seu listview pelo recyclerview.
Com essa lista você consegue mudar seus "dados" atras do notifydatasetchanged